# what is it wrong with int[][]

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi
I have written a code that i will put just a part of that which has a problem.
I have an `arrayList<Point>` which its size is `4`. I have passed the `3` elements of this list to a method but with `System.out.println` I get `3 y` instead of `1 y` !! what is wrong .please help me.thanks

CODE:

```
    public int determinal(Object get, Object get0, Object get1) {
    Point point = (Point) get;
    Point point1 = (Point) get0;
    Point point2 = (Point) get1;
    int[][] data = new int[3][2];
    data[0][0] = point.getX();
    data[0][1] = point.getY();
    data[1][0] = point1.getX();
    data[1][1] = point1.getY();
    data[2][0] = point2.getX();
    data[2][1] = point2.getY();
    System.out.println(data[1][1]);
    return ((data[0][0] - data[2][0]) * (data[2][1] - data[2][1]) * (data[1][0] - 
data[2][1]) * (data[0][1] - data[2][1]));
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
X :225  Y: 86
X :92  Y: 164
X :238  Y: 154
86
164
154
```

**I prefer to print just 164 but it will print all y.**
Also I have another System.out.println that prints the X and Y of all my three points(this method doesn't mentioned above)

Comment: You seem to be confused about the difference between **printing** output to the console and **returning** values from a function.  Your code sample does both.  Perhaps your `determinal()` function is being called more times than you expect?

Comment: Also, since this seems to be homework, you should probably add the `homework` tag to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not really clear what you think the problem is but i think you are just confused because your variables are named inconsistently.

for example, if i remove the code irrelevant to the `System.out.println` call:

```
public int determinal(Object get, Object get0, Object get1) {
    Point point1 = (Point) get0;
    int[][] data = new int[3][2];
    data[1][1] = point1.getY();
    System.out.println(data[1][1]);
    }
```

and then further reduce it:

```
public int determinal(Object get, Object get0, Object get1) {
    System.out.println(((Point) get0).getY());
    }
```

can you see what is happening now?

Comment: I did not get really,I have tested it and the second one print OK ,but why?

Comment: it shouldn't print anything differently to the original method. also, there's no point in assigning the values to an `int[][]`. just refer directly to the points. it's more legible and therefore your less likely to get confused.

Answer (score 0):

I think something wrong with your calling method, can you post the sample for calling method?

Or make sure that you would have some looping control inside your calling method, that would be the reason for this cause.

-Saligh